# R: How to generate a sequence seq() given a condition?

Tags: r, random, vector

I just discovered R and I am trying to work with it.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a vector of numbers, x, between 50 and 100 and with a size of 250 observations.

```
x = sample(seq(50, 100), 250, repeat = T)
```

Now, I want to generate another vector of numbers, y, between 0 and 100, which is the same size as vector x such that each element in y is less than or equal to its equivalent in x.

That is to say that if x[1] is 76, for example, the highest value y[1] could attain when generated is 76. But it could definitely be any other value below 76. In other words and more generally, I want vector y to be generated in such a way that y[i] <= x[i].

I hope I have made my request clearer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is ill-formed, as there are many possible values for `y`.  Please be more specific as to how you want `y` generated.

Comment: Yes please prove some more info.  As is a possible solution is `y <- x`

Comment: Another possibility: `y <- round(runif(length(x))*x)`

Comment: `seq(50, 100, repeat = T)` produces an error for me.  Do you mean  `seq(50, 100, rep = T)`?  Even then `rep = T` does not seem to do anything so you could use `seq(50, 100)` or my preference of `50:100`

Comment: @Henry, you are right! It produces an error but I updated the post and I gave the correct command now! Sorry, I am just a beginner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
y <- x -1 # ...........................

 y <- sapply( x, function(x) runif(n=1, max=x))
 y
 [1]  7.2713788 30.0008063 42.5205775  0.9271717 10.7114456 39.5199145  7.4109775
 [8] 28.3464373 28.5840101 34.0654033 15.0675028 50.2836294 45.9031794 13.5931005
[15] 43.2751738 17.0560824  3.1507491 25.7619129 12.3391448 22.6203684 51.3334810
[22] 37.0481703 33.4733277 37.1304850 26.7984406 66.3844126 40.2775918 47.6379024
[29] 16.2480595 66.8358384 33.3513161 60.2673874 65.6204462 45.6951960  1.5729434
[36] 20.4850357  0.1345737 84.5334203 19.7997451 53.8025623 48.5528486  8.8992123
[43] 90.9651742 28.3584167 41.7728159 46.4790641 17.8129578 83.1906415 37.5114353
[50] 89.5685501 85.2499600
```

Comment: This is a possible solution to my problem; however, I want the elements in vector y to be randomly generated with the elements of vector x as their ceiling!

Comment: Could you please explain in details what the code does? Thank you very much!

Comment: @BenBolker, I'd like you to explain your code too even though I can see the similarities with what DWin wrote. Thank you!

Comment: @SavedByJESUS `runif(3, max=c(1, 2, 3))` will return 3 random values drawn from `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]`, `[0, 3]` respectively.

Comment: @baptiste Thank you very much. Do you speak French? Your name looks French.

Comment: @BenBolker: You've identified my laziness. I didn't know if `runif` were vectorized with regard to the max parameter. The help page is not helpful in this regard. I decided to use what I knew was safe rather than using your admittedly more economical method.